# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/system/system.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\pear')

Tags: php, xampp

```
Warning: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/system/system.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\qdinka\includes\autoload.php on line 9

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/system/system.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\pear') in C:\xampp\htdocs\qdinka\includes\autoload.php on line 9

root is c:/xampp/htdocs pear path is c:/xampp/php/pear
```

anybody have idea why getting error?
tried changing alloverrideall in httpd.conf 
I already saw few posts related but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you checked whether file is present on location `C:/xampp/htdocs/system/system.php`?

Comment: Step 1) Verify whether or not `C:/xampp/htdocs/system/system.php` actually exists on your hard drive.  Step 2) If not,fix your `C:\xampp\htdocs\qdinka\includes\autoload.php` file.

Comment: my system file is on c:/xampp/php/pear/system.php when i moved it on htdocs previous error gone but again next class not found error .

Comment: i m gettingWarning: include_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/includes/template/TemplateBaseClass.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\qdinka\includes\autoload.php on line 14

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:/xampp/htdocs/includes/template/TemplateBaseClass.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\qdinka\includes\autoload.php on line 14

Fatal error: Class 'includes\template\TemplateBase' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\qdinka\includes\pages\LoginPageClass.php on line 16

Answer (score 0):

**Never** use absolute paths, always use **relative** ones. Its easier to import and export your website to another server.

For example, the path `C:\xampp/htdocs/system/system.php` should be written like: `system/system.php`.

You can write that because xampp executes only in the folder `C:\xampp\htdocs\`

> [Here](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/absolute-relative-path.html)'s an article and small explenation about it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check the spelling of specific folder that you are getting through BASEURL

Because i have the same error and  the problem is with the name

Answer (score 0):

The error is as a result of some missing vendor folder.
You just need to run `composer install` in the project directory which will
create a folder named vendor which will have all composer libraries and
`autoload.php` file. The command below worked for me

composer install --ignore-platform-reqs

Answer (score -1):

Actually this is laravel project,and you are executing it without having laravel in your pc.So,there is no issue with that project only thing you need to install the laravel and 2nd thing is that if you have already laravel in your pc then you should update your composer.

Comment: Comment as answer : This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.